# Is there a way to replace a Gradle dependency with another one from the filesystem?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a legacy project in restricted environment. We've found an issue with a third-party OSS library, forked and fixed it. However, this other tool expects the path to the artifact to be extactly as it has been hardcoded into it (it also expects it to be on classpath as a dependency). So, the `dependencies` look somewhate like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.foo', name: 'bar', version: '1.2.3', configuration: 'runtime'
}
```

Where `org.foo:bar:1.2.3` is the artifact that we needed to patch.

Is it possible to override this dependency with its artifact coordinates kept intact, but add something like a `files` section to it? If so, how? Can it be done using module substitution?

We're using an ancient version of Gradle -- 4.10.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While contributing the fix to the OSS library should be your end goal, you can work around the issue in the following way:

- Add the patched file to a local repository under `<root>/org/foo/bar/1.2.3/bar-1.2.3.jar` with its matching metadata file, assuming Maven POM: `<root>/org/foo/bar/1.2.3/bar-1.2.3.pom`
- Define this repository *before* other repositories in your build

  ```
  repositories {
      maven {
          name = "localRepo"
          url = "<root>"
      }
      // Other repositories below
  }
  ```
- When Gradle resolve this dependency, it will pick the one from the local repository given it has metadata and respects the repository layout.

  - This might require running with `--refresh-dependencies` to get Gradle to notice the *changed* dependency.

NOTE: Outside of a legacy / restricted environment, I would *not* recommend doing this. You are effectively shadowing an artifact in a give context, making your build brittle.

Comment: Interesting hack! Thanks! And -- yes -- ultimately, we do try to contribute back fixes. In this particular case, our fix is a company-specific customization which nobody would be interested in.